# I am not able to build android app in Unity3D. Error Gradle initialization failed

Tags: java, android, c#, unity-game-engine

I am using an empty Unity Android project. I am not able to build APK since 2 weeks. I am getting this error

> CommandWithNoStdoutInvokationFailure: Gradle initialization failed.
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.RunWithShellExecute (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg) (at <4132c5c2cd7b45b09ef33302ae416489>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJavaWithShellExecute (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String error) (at <4132c5c2cd7b45b09ef33302ae416489>:0)

Here is the full Error:

[image: Error Image]

I am not getting any solution on the internet as in Latest version of Unity 2019.1.6f1, JDK, Android SDK and NDK are installed within Unity (installed while installing Unity).

I have installed new Windows 10 in my another Drive and Installed same Unity Version in the new Windows 10. And it built successfully without any issue. However I am not able to build it on my current Operation System. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone because this took me forever to fix with no other solutions available online for this exact error message and multiple users reporting the issue.

I think this problem might be caused by some type of permissions/file access problem. In my case my Unity project was located on a network share that was being synced for offline access. As soon as I copied the files to my local C:\ drive the problem went away.

Comment: This. This is it. WOW. I just spent two days chasing this down. Thank you. For reference, all I did was launch the Unity hub as administrator, and that solves everything.

Comment: @TypeKazt I totally forgot about making this post and literally a week ago I was thinking to myself.... why do I keep my code base on my C: drive. Glad this helped. I've had on going issues with synced/offline network shares not performing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah gradle build causes errors every time, change build system from "gradle" to "internal".

Comment: Changing Build System to "Internal" is not available in newer Unity Version (Unity 2019.1.6). Please reply.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1629347/gradle-build-fails-on-unity-2019.html
Something similar?

Comment: Similar, but not same. My Error was "CommandWithNoStdoutInvokationFailure:" Please refer to this error image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tre0n.png